# Unable to modify a file entered as an argument JAVA

Tags: java

I'm trying to get this to work but it doesn't and I don't get why,
It's supposed to be a script where I enter an argument file and it replaces it with the correct replaced characters in it. 
It doesn't replace the file I entered as argument.
I can get it to work If I place the whole code in the main function without calling a method.

Thanks.

```
public class Rename 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        File origine = new File(args[0]);
        renameFile(origine);
    }
    public static void renameFile(File fileOriginal) throws IOException
    {
        try 
        {
            File tempFile = File.createTempFile("buffer", ".tmp");
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(tempFile);

            Reader fr = new FileReader(fileOriginal);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

            while (br.ready()) 
            {
                fw.write(br.readLine().replace("#/A#" , "Á"));
            }

            fw.close();
            br.close();
            fr.close();

            tempFile.renameTo(fileOriginal);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide some input and expected result?

Comment: I run the code. It's OK. Can you add the error log and the environment to the question?

Comment: the temporary file is most certainly not in the same location as the file from the argument. It will be created in the systems temporary directory and will be renamed there.

Comment: @HerrDerb `renameTo()` can move files between directories in the same file system. There is no 'most certainly not' about it.

Comment: @EJP Sorry, you are right. That feels lika a misleading design decision though. Especially as there is a separate move functionality.

Comment: @HerbDerb There is now, but there wasn't in 1995 when `renameTo()` appeared.

Answer (score 3):

- `renameTo()` returns a value. You are ignoring it.
- You can't rename a file to the name of an existing file. You have to ensure the target name doesn't exist.
- `ready()` is not a test for end of stream: see the Javadoc.
- A method that modifies the content of a file should not be called `renameFile()`.